# Selenium select element which isnt directly in the page source in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

For instance I have this website: https://skinport.com/item/stattrak-usp-s-black-lotus-minimal-wear/6128018 and want to get the current price of the item. Selenium doesn't find the element by class name, XPath or css selector. I think that's just because the page source doesn't have the price. The site consists of a few scripts which prints the current price

So I have something like this in python:

```
driver.get("https://skinport.com/item/stattrak-usp-s-black-lotus-field-tested/6196388")
print(price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div'))
```

And I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

With

```
print(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR("#content > div.ItemPage > div.ItemPage-column.ItemPage-column--right > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ItemPage-price > div.ItemPage-value > div")))
```

I get this error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a wait.
You should let the page loaded before accessing that element.
The preferred way to do that is to use the expected conditions explicit waits.
Also you are missing the `text` method to retrieve the text from the web element.
Also, your locator is bad.
Something like this should work:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://skinport.com/item/stattrak-usp-s-black-lotus-field-tested/6196388")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ItemPage-price div.Tooltip-link"))).text
print(price)
```

Comment: it's OKay, we all are learning new things all the time. You even could put there a dummy pause, like `time.sleep(5)` while this is not elegant and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

My guest is, you didn't add an implicit/explicit wait to your driver session. Your xpath seems to work.
Post your code. Maybe we could figure it out together.

[image: screen capture]

The link to the documentation
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html